# Counting First Letter that occur in a line and showing the summary in shell/linux using grep

Tags: shell, grep

I have a log that look like this

```
I:5000:GAME
I:5000:GAME
I-:5000:GAME
I-:5000:GAME
E:5000:GAME
E:5000:GAME
E:5000:GAME
E:5000:GAME
E:5000:GAME
J:5000:GAME
J:5000:GAME
J:5000:GAME
L:5000:GAME
M:5000:GAME
K:5000:GAME
```

What I wanted to do is count line that starts with letter E,I-,J and sort it in Descending order.

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
5  E
3  J
2  I-
```

this is what im trying to type

```
sort /home/prod-dev/progex_logs.txt | egrep '^E|^I|^J' | cut -f1 -d: | uniq -c
```

my file is progex_logs.txt but its not showing the answer that i want

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sort data | cut -f1 -d: | uniq -c
```

This sorts the input data lexically, extracts just the first column, and then pipes the result to `uniq -c`, which collapses duplicate lines and calculates a count of how many lines were collapsed.  Given you sample input, this generates:

```
  5 E
  2 I-
  2 I
  3 J
  1 K
  1 L
  1 M
```

If you just want E, I-, and J, you can filter those out using the `egrep` command that user2254435 posted, like this:

```
sort data | egrep '^I-|^E|^J'  | cut -f1 -d: | uniq -c
```

Which would get you:

```
  5 E
  2 I-
  3 J
```

### So what does this do?

The first command:

```
sort data
```

Generates a lexically sorted version of the data.  Given your sample
input, we get:

```
E:5000:GAME
E:5000:GAME
E:5000:GAME
E:5000:GAME
E:5000:GAME
I-:5000:GAME
I-:5000:GAME
I:5000:GAME
I:5000:GAME
J:5000:GAME
J:5000:GAME
J:5000:GAME
K:5000:GAME
L:5000:GAME
M:5000:GAME
```

We then [pipe](http://www.dsj.net/compedge/shellbasics1.html) the output to the next command, `cut -f1 -d:`, using
the `|` operator, which lets us send *stdout* from one command to
*stdin* of another command.  This commands reads as input the output
from the `sort` command, and the extracts the first (`-f1`)
colon-delimited field (`-d:`).  This gives us:

```
E
E
E
E
E
I-
I-
I
I
J
J
J
K
L
M
```

We then pipe the output to `uniq -c`, which collapses duplicate lines
and generates a count of how many lines were collapsed.  So, given
input like:

```
E
E
E
E
E
```

Running `uniq -c` gives us:

```
5 E
```

For more information about all this, see the man pages for [sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html),
[cut](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html), and [uniq](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html).

Comment: Sir Larsks, what this codes does "| cut -f1 -d: |"?
if you can please explain it, since a beginner. thank you

Comment: I have updated my answer with some explanatory comments.

Comment: this is what Ive entered, but it is not running sort /home/prod-dev/progex_logs.txt | egrep '^E|^I|^J' | cut -f1 -d: | uniq -c

Comment: Comments aren't really good for this sort of thing.  Update your question with the command you ran and either (a) what errors it produced or (b) what the output looked like.  Or both.

Comment: If you only want `I-` and not `I` in the output, you need to modify your `egrep` command: `sort /home/prod-dev/progex_logs.txt | egrep '^E|^I-|^J' | cut -f1 -d: | uniq -c`  If you really need the fields reversed, pipe the output of `uniq -c` to `awk '{print $2,$1}'`.  Also, see my comment on Raghuram's answer showing how to do the whole thing with just `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using awk

```
cat ip.txt | awk 'BEGIN{IC=0;JC=0;EC=0}{if(index($0,"I-")>0)IC++;else if(index($0,"E:")>0)EC++;else if(index($0,"J:")>0)JC++;}END{printf("I- %d\n",IC);printf("E: %d\n",EC);printf("J: %d\n",JC);}'
```

Comment: That's a ridiculously complicated `awk` command.  Consider `awk -F: '$1 ~ /E|J|I-/ {totals[$1]++} END {for (i in totals) print i,totals[i]}' < ip.txt`

Comment: The code is not complex. Logic is i have 3 variables for 3 patterns(one for each pattern). Increment the counter depending on pattern and print the same. You idea is also good.

Answer (score -1):

egrep '^I-|^E|^J' test.dat|wc -l

This does an extended grep using the given pattern.  The result is passed on to the wc command to count the resulting lines from the egrep.

Comment: I don't think this will give him the sample output he is looking for, which is a summary of the number of lines that have the same initial field.

Comment: You are correct. I should have read the question more carefully.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common way to do it with `awk`

```
awk -F: '/^(E|I-|J)/ {a[$1]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
I- 2
E 5
J 3
```

---

To get it sorted, you can do:

```
awk -F: '/^(E|I-|J)/ {a[$1]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file | sort -rk2
E 5
J 3
I- 2
```

---

How it works

```
awk -F: '                   # setting field separator to :
/^(E|I-|J)/ {               # run this section only if starting with E, I- or J
    a[$1]++}                # add field #1 to array a
END {                       # end section
    for (i in a)            # looping through all element in array
    print i,a[i]}           # print element name and the number of elements
    ' file | sort -rk2      # sort output by column #2 in reverse order
```

Comment: It's almost like you read my comment on Raghuram's answer and made it your own.

Comment: @larsks I did not use any of your solution, I did write my own, so giving one minus on this is not fear.  Its just a normal way of using `awk`, and I read your comment first now.